# Flutter : Editable PDF Viewer for both iOS and Android

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Am new to Flutter I would like to know a PDF Viewer which can be editable on both iOS and Android.

Am looking for a library or a pluggin which can view the pdf from local path and is editable if the pdf is editable.

I came across few libraries which is either filled with bugs or is only editable on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

There are too options I guess PDFTron and PSPDKit but both of them are paid